# PHP File Returns Error 500 when it Executed Inside folder with 777 permissions

Tags: php, joomla, chmod

This problem begin when I installed the Qivva calendar Joomla module. The AJAX request return `ajax failure` it returns 500 error.
I think it because the ajax request of [Qivva](http://extensions.qivva.com/demo/eventlist-calendar.html) is not to the root of the site, It goes to this URL

`/modules/mod_eventlistcalqajax/mod_ajaxloader.php?modid=42&Itemid=4&el_mcal_month=1&el_mcal_year=2012`

While, in default joomla chmod the `modules` folder to 777. my Question is, Why php can't be executed inside chmoded 777 folder?

Comment: A 500 error isn't necessarily permissions related. It could be an error in the code or configuration of the server. Check the logs to see exactly what the error is.

Comment: Joomla chmod modules folder to 777? Double and tripple check plz.

Comment: @RichAdams A 500 error may well be permissions related if the OP's running [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html). It expects folders to be 0755 and scripts to be 0644. Otherwise, 500 ensues.

Answer (score 0):

The [code 500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) means internal server error. That means you should check your `error.log` for more information. I do not think that it is related to the 777 permissions.